# Why does Option<&str>::cloned() not produce an Option<String>?

Tags: rust

I have an `Option<&str>` and I would like to end up with an `Option<String>`. For other types, `Option::cloned` would be an easy way to do that. The docs even say:

> pub fn cloned(self) -> `Option<T>`
>
> Maps an `Option<&T>` to an `Option<T>` by cloning the contents of the option.

However, trying this actually results in a compile error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let unowned_str_maybe: Option<&str> = Some("abc");
    let owned_str_maybe: Option<String> = unowned_str_maybe.cloned();  // <-- unsatisfied trait bounds
    println!("{:?}", owned_str_maybe);
}

/* Compile error is:

 error[E0599]: the method `cloned` exists for enum `Option<&str>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:5:61
    |
5   |       let owned_str_maybe: Option<String> = unowned_str_maybe.cloned();  // <-- unsatisfied trait bounds
    |                                                               ^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Option<&str>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `str: Sized`
            `str: Clone`
            `Option<&str>: Iterator`
            which is required by `&mut Option<&str>: Iterator`
*/
```

Using a more verbose (less idiomatic?) construction of `.map(|x| x.to_string())` *does* compile. Why does `Option::cloned` not work for converting `&str` to `String`?

Comment: The answer is right there in the error message -- `&str` doesn't implement `Clone` (along with the other traits mentioned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `Clone` (which is used by `Option::cloned`) is used only to convert from `&T` to `T`, not from `&T` to `U`, even if semantically `U` is an owned version of `&T` (as `String` is to `&str`). In fact, you probably wouldn't expect this function to compile:

```
fn cloned(input: &str) -> String {
    input.clone()
}
```

But `Option::cloned` is, essentially, `.map(cloned)`, so it will work only if `cloned` works.

In fact, your approach with `to_string` is probably idiomatic. You probably could use function reference instead of closure, i.e. `.map(ToString::to_string)`, or replace `to_string` with `to_owned`, but this is not so important.